# prolog parsing operations problems

Tags: parsing, prolog

Here is the problem. I want to do a prolog program on `count(a*b*c, * , N)` which will count the `*` in   `a*b*c` and return    `N=2`.

How can i achieve this?

I have done some research, either passing it as s string or using a list to separate `a*b*c`.

However, so far nothing is successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `a*b*c` is a simplified compound term:

```
?- write_canonical(a*b*c).
*(*(a,b),c)
```

You can see that `*` is just the functor of a binary relation, and the visit of the expression tree can be done using the [univ](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28=..%29/2) builtin:

```
count(Expression, Request, N) :-
    (   Expression =.. [Op, Left, Right]
    ->  count(Left, Request, NLeft),
        count(Right, Request, NRight),
        (   Request == Op
        ->  N is NLeft + NRight + 1
        ;   N is NLeft + NRight
        )
    ;   N = 0
    ).
```

This accepts trees expressions with any binary operator, but also, for instance

```
?- count(e(a,e(b,c)),e,N).
N = 2.
```

Comment: thanks, but i think this is not recursive. if i have more terms like z*b*d*e, then i need to add more conditions.

Comment: it's recursive, on count(Left,...), count(Right,...)

Comment: oos, my mistake, u are right, it is recursive. After much check through, i think this answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

It will only count * but modifying it to count other things should be so hard:

```
main :-
    atom_chars('a*b*c', CharList),
    star_counter(CharList, Count),
    write(Count).

star_counter([], 0).

star_counter(['*'|R], Count) :-
    star_counter(R, Sum),
    Count is Sum + 1.

star_counter([H|R], Count) :-
    star_counter(R, Count).
```

**EDIT** Here's a version with a parameter for the character you want to look up:

```
main :-
    atom_chars('a*b*c', CharList),
    star_counter('*',CharList, Count),
    write(Count).

star_counter(_,[], 0).

star_counter(X,[X|R], Count) :-
    star_counter(X,R, Sum),
    Count is Sum + 1.

star_counter(X,[_|R], Count) :-
    star_counter(X,R, Count).
```

Comment: hi, do u mind explain why u use 2nd rule : star_counter([H|R], Count) :- star_counter(R, Count). and if now i want to vary * to any math operator like + or -  how can i modify this part

Comment: Sure :) The first one increases the count value if a star was found. But for any other character I want count to stay the same but still move forward in the list. [H|R] means H holds the head of the list (first element) and R the rest of the list. I hope it's a little clearer.

Comment: yes, i got ur idea, thanks so much, then for varying math operator part. how can i do that. i am having trouble to write the base case.

Comment: Edited my answer with a second version of the code. Should be pretty much what you're looking for. Too many small changes to do it in comment.

Comment: thanks, but i tried without main and consult the program, then typed star_counter(+,a*b+c,N). i think the result is false, wat shall i do? sorry for my bad english

Comment: The call to atom_chars(...) is essential.

Comment: is there anyway we force the input to become atom_chars